# SQL Server stored procedure timeout with some users of database

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, timeout

I have problems with a particular stored procedure in SQL Server 2005. This SP is called form ADO.NET with a particular user of SQL Server, for example user1, and I get timeout. If I call the SP from the same application with different user of SQL Server, for example user2, it works fine. From Management no problems, user1 and user2 execute the SP in the same time.

I've tried to recompile the SP, delete and recreate it, and set isolation level of SP to read uncommited.

What's the matter?? What can I do??

Thanks.

Comment: Did you use Profiler to see all activity from the time of calling this procedure to the time of delivering/timeout? What is the difference between users or their roles?

Comment: Users have the same permissions and roles for this database. With the Profiler I made a record from start to timeout, but I didn't see any strange. Really, I don't have much knowledge with Profiler. User1 is the user in the web.config of main application, and 95% of database engine's traffic is performed with this user.

Comment: Your explanation is quite unclear for me. I mean to capture two logs (with full events), both with starting time before running this procedure till result. Is there any difference there? I faced the same problem when server took bad execution plan for different WHERE-clauses. Once there was enough to use Nested Loops join (because of high selectivity of one parameter), next time this join was unacceptable, because another parameter took a half of table (millions of rows), then time to calculate this amount with nested loops join drastically increased! But you said, in SSMS everything was ok...